# tfsbuild delete/destroy - founds no builds for build specification

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

There are 100s of builds left in our build definition indefinitely, regardless of the retention settings: i want to delete builds with scripts, i am trying run from remote PC. our tfs server is 2015.2.

```
tfsbuild destroy /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/ProjectCollection /dateRange:01/01/2017~31/12/2017 /buildDefinition:teamProject\Builddefintion
```

output shows: **No builds found for build specification**. even though there are many builds meets the criteria. any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about XAML builds or the newer build system?

Comment: Hi, its new - vNext builds

Answer (score 1):

`Tfsbuild delete/destroy` only availabe for Xaml builds. And need to `delete` first then `destroy`.

For vNext builds, you can try to delete them with the REST API ([Delete a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#delete-a-build)):

```
DELETE http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_apis/build/builds/{build Id}?api-version=2.0
```

You can use below PowerShell script to delete all the builds which compeleted in the year 2017 for the specific build definiiton:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/Collection",
   [string]$projectName = "ProjectName",
   [string]$builddefinitionID = "56",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get builds list which completed in the year 2017
$buildsUrl = "$($collectionurl)/$projectName/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$builddefinitionID&statusFilter=completed&api-version=2.0"   
$builds = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildsUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value | where({$_.finishTime -like '*2017*'})

#Delete the builds 
foreach ($build in $builds.id)
{
$deleteurl = "$($collectionurl)/$projectName/_apis/build/builds/$build"+"?api-version=2.0"

$result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $deleteurl -Method Delete -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})

Write-Host "Builds deleted with the ID" : $build 
}
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the quick help. i am using tfs2015 on premises . I don't see the tokens in options. Can you please let me know other authentication way to use  the script ?

Comment: @chandu Create a `*.txt` file, copy above script to the `*.txt` file, --> provide the correct parameters, save it as `*.ps1` file. (Change the file extension, *.txt to *.ps1) -->, run the `*.ps1` file

Comment: @chandu You can set the `password` of the account as the token. In short, just ignore the 'token', just specific your user name and password and other parameters in above script.Then run it locally or on any machine which can connect to TFS server, don't need to run in TFS.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, trying it now , first time, its  shown as Build deleted with id =5032, then after i get this message Invoke-RestMethod : The operation has timed out.
At C:\Work\scripts\delBuilds.ps1:15 char:12
+ $builds = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildsUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorizatio ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: it seems, few of the builds deleted partially, i can still see summary, with no info, when i am trying the same script again, i am always getting the above timeout error.

Comment: @chandu Everything works as expected on my side. Even try the script again, if the builds already deleted, then it will not retrieve the build ids. You can try to delete only a specific build with the REST API directly to check if that works for you. e.g.: `DELETE https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/build/builds/393?api-version=2.0`

Comment: when i tried delete the specific build, it got deleted completely. the script deleted some of the builds, but not all completely because of timeout error. not sure why.  **Also  would it be possible to give the logic to skip the builds older than 30 days , but delete rest ??**

Comment: Hi Andy, tried the script again on another build definition (CI), looks like there are ~1000 builds. script didn't work. while script running  i could see message _reading web response , reading response stream ( no of bytes read xxxxxx)_ and does nothing.

Comment: @chandu First, there are minFinishTime and maxFinishTime filters that can get the related builds in a time range. Secondly, regarding timeout issue, try to call REST API in a job (e.g. 10 requests in a job: replace foreach to for loop) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6