# TFS Database growth is increasing at a rapid speed

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfsbuild

When are using TFS 2018, and have just started creating our build and release definitions. We have noticed that the database is increasing in size rapidly to the point over virtual machines are shutting down due to lack of space. Is there any thing else I could do to reduce this growth.

I have tried the following:

- Clean agent directories after each build
- Set Retention of all build and release definitions to 1 - 2 days
- Delete the current agents working directories
- Run `EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent 1`
- Run `EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 100000`

Even after all this, it has only freed up around ~6GB.

**Blob Size by Owner ID:**

[image: Blob Size by Owner ID]

**File Container Distribution:**

[image: File Container Distribution]

**Database Growth by Day:**

[image]

Comment: *Clean agent directories after each build* That won't help with this problem. How big are your builds and are you publishing only the necessary artifacts?

Comment: @DanielMann So some builds the run units tests, others create artifacts which only contains files from specific folders in specific branches. I have tried to reduce the overhead as much as possible. Is there a way I can delete old artifacts or is that done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> **TFS VC Content**
>
> When TFS version control branches, folders, and files
> are deleted, they are **only logically deleted** - their content is still
> available in history. TFS VC branches, folders, or individual files
> can be physically deleted using the **destroy command via tf.exe**.

So in the end a series of commands to be executed:

```
tf destroy /i /startcleanup "$/<BranchName or FileName>" /collection:http://<TFS_URI>:8080/tfs/<CollectionName>
```

and also (only for XML):

```
tfsbuild destroy /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/ProjectCollection /dateRange:01/01/2017~31/12/2017 /buildDefinition:teamProject\Builddefintion
```

For newer type of builds check: [tfsbuild delete/destroy - founds no builds for build specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695748/tfsbuild-delete-destroy-founds-no-builds-for-build-specification)

References:

- [Clean up your Team Project Collection prior to migrating to VSTS](https://jessehouwing.net/tfs-clean-up-your-project-collection/)
- [Cleaning up old data in Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/clean-up-data?view=azure-devops)
- [How To Permanently Delete Files from TFS](https://confidentcoder.com/how-to-permanently-delete-files-from-tfs-b3d5e7f0307e)

Comment: Is this command just for the version control? If so, it is more the build files that are causing most of the issues. Does that command work for builds as well?

Comment: @Ross, Hi, I added another command: `tfsbuild destroy`. But also a good I think a good article to walk-through: "Clean up your Team Project Collection prior to migrating to VSTS"